# Unable to get textarea value with LockerService

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

Very straightforward, I have a textarea element in my component which I need to get the value of.

TestApp.app

```
<aura:application >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jquery}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="textcount" type="Integer" default="0"/>
    <div id="textcounter" class="slds-text-body--small" >{!v.textcount}/10000</div>
    <textarea aura:id="message-input"  maxlength="10000" class="slds-input" type="text" id="message-input"  />
</aura:application>
```

TestAppController.js

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        $('#message-input').bind('keyup click blur focus change paste',function() {
            console.log("JQuery test");
            console.log($('#message-input'));
            console.log($('#message-input').toString());
            console.log($('#message-input').val());
            console.log($('#message-input').value);
            console.log("Javascript test");
            console.log(document.getElementById('message-input'));
            console.log(document.getElementById('message-input').toString());
            console.log(document.getElementById('message-input').value);
            console.log("Aura test");
            console.log(cmp.find('message-input'));
            console.log(cmp.find('message-input').getElement());
            console.log(cmp.find('message-input').getElement().value);
            cmp.set("v.textcount", $('#message-input').val().length);
        });
    } 
})
```

Output with LockerService off.

```
app.js:825 JQuery test
app.js:826 [textarea#message-input.slds-input, context: document, selector: "#message-input"]
app.js:827 [object Object]
app.js:828 mytext
app.js:829 undefined
app.js:830 Javascript test
app.js:831 <textarea class=​"slds-input" maxlength=​"10000" type=​"text" id=​"message-input" data-aura-rendered-by=​"8:​2;​a">​</textarea>​
app.js:832 [object HTMLTextAreaElement]
app.js:833 mytext
app.js:834 Aura test
app.js:835 componentConstructor {$concreteComponentId$: undefined, $shouldAutoDestroy$: true, $rendered$: true, $inUnrender$: false, $localId$: "message-input"…}
app.js:836 <textarea class=​"slds-input" maxlength=​"10000" type=​"text" id=​"message-input" data-aura-rendered-by=​"8:​2;​a">​</textarea>​
app.js:837 mytext
```

output with LockerService on

```
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:11 JQuery test
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:12 [Object, context: Object, selector: "#message-input"]
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:13 [object Object]
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:14 
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:15 undefined
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:16 Javascript test
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:17 Object {jQuery224047175119781793451: Object}
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:18 SecureElement: [object HTMLTextAreaElement]{ key: {"$namespace$":"mynamespace"} }
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:19 undefined
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:20 Aura test
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:21 Object {}
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:22 Object {jQuery224047175119781793451: Object}
components/mynamespace/TestApp.js:23 undefined
```

With LockerService off, everything works well and the value updates according to the length of the textarea's value. 
With LockerService on, it's always 0.

**When using an input element, the text is fetched correctly , but when using a textarea, it does not fetch the text.**

Comment: I am noticing that in the Locker source code: https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureElement.js the whitelisted attributes for `textarea` do not include `value`. This seems like a severe oversight. Compare with `input` which does have `value` whitelisted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `value` property of `textarea` has just been whitelisted and should be available next week.

Comment: **select** element doesn't have **value** attribute whitelisted either. Also, when this changes are going to be live? I'm still having the **textarea** issue. Thnx!

Answer (score 3):

See my comment above but if you want a functional workaround - which is also more in line with the direction Lightning is going in general - you could use the built-in `ui:textarea` component and bind an attribute to its value. Then don't use jQuery at all to get its value but just fetch the attribute using `component.get`.